# Two NICs in same subnet but different physical networks

Tags: linux-networking

I have a PC that must connect to two physically separate networks.  unfortunately both of those networks have used the 192.168.1.0 network with netmask 255.255.255.0.  I have tried to assigned my IPs as 192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.102.   however I am unable to ping my PC from either of the networks.  The only way I have been able to get connectivity is to put both NICs on the same physical network.  This however will not work as there are duplicated IPs on the two networks so they cannot be connected.  The two networks cannot be changed as it is hard coded configuration that must remain.  my PC is running red hat RHEL 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think *maybe* you could have done it if there weren't address conflicts by adding an entry to the routing table for each IP-address you want to reach, and possibly creating very convoluted iptables rules to direct ARP traffic. But, unlikely.

You are probably going to have to do some kind of NAT. For example, put a standard NAT router's WAN port in your PC and the LAN side in one of the networks. Then configure port forwards to reach whatever you need.

But I would see if it's indeed not feasible to renumber one of the networks. Use a non-conventional one like 10.91.0.0/16. I like setting up my LANs that way for this reason.

Comment: the pcs that need to reach my pc do not have conflicting IPs.. just other equipment that prevents making it one big network.  I tried route tables but likely did it incorrectly.  i am not a network engineer.  how would I clear the routing tables and then do it correctly?

Comment: @hillsm you can reboot to clear the routing tables. Then for each PC you want to reach, you need to explicitly add a rule to make it go to NIC1 or NIC2. But then you have ARP to deal with. Your PC is going to broadcast 'who has 192.168.0.x?' and then you get two replies. You're going to have to analyze all traffic with `tcpdump` and wireshark to see exactly what traffic you need to redirect/block. It won't be a trivial task.